# How to have different OpenMP threads execute different tasks

Tags: openmp

I am using open MP to speed up the flux calculation in my program. I basically want OpenMP to carry out both of these left and right flux calculations in parallel. But on the contrary, the following code takes even more time with the `#pragma` directives. What do i modify to get it right?

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
{

#pragma omp single
{//first condition
//cerr<<"Executed thread 0"<<endl;
        if ( (fabs(lcellMach-1.0)<EPSILON) || ( (lcellMach-1.0) > 0.0 ) ){//purpose of Epsilon!!!!
                FluxP[0] = rhol * vnl;
                FluxP[1] = rhol * ul * vnl + Pl*nx;
                FluxP[2] = rhol * vl * vnl + Pl*ny;
                FluxP[3] = rhol * wl * vnl + Pl*nz;
                FluxP[4] = rhol * ((GAMMA * Pl / (rhol * (GAMMA-1.0))) + ((ul*ul + vl*vl + wl*wl)/2.0)) * vnl;
        }else if ( (fabs(lcellMach+1.0)<EPSILON) || ( (lcellMach+1.0) < 0.0 ) ){
                FluxP[0] = FluxP[1] = FluxP[2] = FluxP[3] = FluxP[4] = 0.0;// If flow direction is opposite the Flux + is zero
        }else {
                double ql = (ul*ul + vl*vl + wl*wl);// how did this come
                FluxP[0] = rhol * lcell_a * (lcellMach+1.0)*(lcellMach+1.0) / 4.0;
                FluxP[1] = FluxP[0] * ( ul + (nx*(0.0-vnl + 2.0*lcell_a)/GAMMA) );
                FluxP[2] = FluxP[0] * ( vl + (ny*(0.0-vnl + 2.0*lcell_a)/GAMMA) );
                FluxP[3] = FluxP[0] * ( wl + (nz*(0.0-vnl + 2.0*lcell_a)/GAMMA) );
                FluxP[4] = FluxP[0] * (  ((ql - vnl*vnl)/2.0) + (((GAMMA-1.0)*vnl + 2.0*lcell_a)*((GAMMA-1.0)*vnl + 2.0*lcell_a) / (2.0*(GAMMA*GAMMA-1.0)))  );
        }
}//end of 1st
#pragma omp single
{//second condition
//cerr<<"Executed thread 1"<<endl;
        if ((fabs(rcellMach+1.0)<EPSILON) || ((rcellMach+1.0) < 0.0)) {
                FluxM[0] = rhor * vnr;
                FluxM[1] = rhor * ur * vnr + Pr*nx;
                FluxM[2] = rhor * vr * vnr + Pr*ny;
                FluxM[3] = rhor * wr * vnr + Pr*nz;
                FluxM[4] = rhor * ((GAMMA * Pr / (rhor * (GAMMA-1.0))) + ((ur*ur + vr*vr + wr*wr)/2.0)) * vnr;
        }else if ((fabs(rcellMach-1.0)<EPSILON) || ((rcellMach-1.0) > 0.0)) {
                FluxM[0] = FluxM[1] = FluxM[2] = FluxM[3] = FluxM[4] = 0.0;
        }else {
                tempFlux[0] = rhor * vnr;
                tempFlux[1] = rhor * ur * vnr + Pr*nx;
                tempFlux[2] = rhor * vr * vnr + Pr*ny;
                tempFlux[3] = rhor * wr * vnr + Pr*nz;
                tempFlux[4] = rhor * ((GAMMA * Pr / (rhor * (GAMMA-1.0))) + ((ur*ur + vr*vr + wr*wr)/2.0)) * vnr;

                double qr = (ur*ur + vr*vr + wr*wr);
                tempFluxP[0] = rhor * rcell_a * (rcellMach+1.0)*(rcellMach+1.0) / 4.0;
                tempFluxP[1] = tempFluxP[0] * ( ur + (nx*(0.0-vnr + 2.0*rcell_a)/GAMMA) );
                tempFluxP[2] = tempFluxP[0] * ( vr + (ny*(0.0-vnr + 2.0*rcell_a)/GAMMA) );
                tempFluxP[3] = tempFluxP[0] * ( wr + (nz*(0.0-vnr + 2.0*rcell_a)/GAMMA) );
                tempFluxP[4] = tempFluxP[0] * (  ((qr - vnr*vnr)/2.0) + (((GAMMA-1.0)*vnr + 2.0*rcell_a)*((GAMMA-1.0)*vnr + 2.0*rcell_a) / (2.0*(GAMMA*GAMMA-1.0)))  );

                for (int j=0; j<O; j++) FluxM[j] = tempFlux[j] - tempFluxP[j];
        }
}
}//pragma
```

Urgent help required. Thanks.

Comment: #pragma omp single: The omp single directive identifies a section of code that must be run by a **single available thread**.

Comment: Then what do i do here? I need to execute both of the blocks of code inside the single sections in parallel.

Comment: This can be done; @nhahtdh's comment describes the problem, and Hristo's answer correctly describes how to do what you were trying to do.   But this seems like an overly low-level place to be doing the parallelization.   Presumably at some higher level of the code you're doing this flux calculation over many cells, correct?  That loop seems like a more profitable target for parallelization.

Comment: Yes right. I will look into it. Probably parallelizing the code which calls the flux functions might help.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the `sections` construct:

```
#pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(2)
{
   #pragma omp section
   {
      ... code that updates FluxP ...
   }
   #pragma omp section
   {
      ... code that updates FluxM ...
   }
}
```

But your code doesn't seem like it would take much time to do the calculations (no big `for` loops inside for example) so the overhead that OpenMP will put onto it will most likely be more time consuming than the saving in computation time and hence the parallel version will most likely execute slower than the serial.